# Is it possible to read EF Code First Connection String from Azure Role Environment

Tags: entity-framework, azure, code-first, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure Worker Role which is using Entity Framework Code First (5.0) to talk to a SQL Azure database.  Currently I have the connection string in the app.config of the worker role however I would like to move the connection string into the Woker Role's Role Environment settings in order to make connection string changes easier for my live services colleagues without requiring redeployment of the Azure package.

Currently I am initializing the context in the form:

```
protected BaseContext()
        : base("name=DataStore")
{  
    try
            {
                ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();

                var storeConnection = (SqlConnection)currentDbConn;
                new SqlCommand("declare @i int", storeConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                currentDbConn.Close();
                Trace.TraceError("Error occured while getting connection to context", ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
}
```

I haven't been able to override DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) to be able to pull the connection string from RoleEnvironment and I've also tried creating a new SqlConnection and assigning that the Database.Connection property but there's no setter :/.

Has anyone any ideas or guidance on how this could be achieved?

Thanks in advance for taking time to look at this question.

Comment: Note that EF will search for the connection string that has the same name as the class that was inherited from the DbContext class. Is it that in your case?

Comment: I am also having this issue have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest either create a ContextFactory class or a static Factory method on your context like this

```
public class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public static BaseContext Create()
    {
        return new BaseContext(
            RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("connectionString"));
    }
}
```